# Error while signing jar

Tags: java, jar, signing

I am trying to sign the jar, but I am getting this exception-

> [exec] jarsigner: Certificate chain
>   not found for:
>   pvktmp:e40b0b30-dcc9-4aef-8450-15c2437a4959.
>   pvktmp:e40b0b30-dcc9-4aef-8450-15c2437a4959
>   must reference a valid KeyStore key
>   entry containing a private key and
>   corresponding public key certificate
>   chain.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use correct certificate file to sign the jar since the certificate you are trying to sign the jar may have been corrupted.